# Find Open Metro Apps using Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I'm looking for a way to programmatically find all Metro apps currently running on a Windows 8 PC using Powershell. I'm sure there's an easy way because these open apps shows up in the Task Manager under the "Apps" section. I was able to find all apps currently installed, but not all Metro apps that are currently running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of an API to identify metro apps, but I think this might do what you want:

```
function Get-ModernAppProcess {
    $wildcard = "$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\*" # Native Apps
    $wwa = "$env:windir\System32\WWAHost.exe"     # HTML+Javascript Apps
    Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Path -like $wildcard -or $_.Path -eq $wwa}
}
```

Note that you might need to run this script with admin permissions to identify all the running processes.